# Responsive js library

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anybody tell me what is the library used [here](http://www.francescobertelli.com/)

I have to do a website like this one so if anyone has encounter this library please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have a Web Browser. They are quite common nowadays. You could download one from here: https://www.google.com/chrome/‎ and then use the built-in developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) to see which scripts are included:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hit F12 in chrome and after expanding head tag you can see all the libraries used in that site.

Answer (score 0):

No library is used to do it. The code to do it was written by the website author. Good luck.